# Can we design a system in react where all the filters and grids can be stored in one file to use as props to pages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-state-management

This same code is written for multiple pages with some changes and redux is implemented for state management. Please guide me I want to write simple and easy code.

```
class Grid extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.loadMoreRef = React.createRef();
        this.state = {
            loaded: true
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let { search_payload } = this.props;
            let payload = { ...search_payload };
            payload.statusId = this.props.statusId;
            this.props.unitSearchAction({
                type: "UNIT_SEARCH",
                value: payload
            });
            resolve("");
        });

    loadMore() {
        let unit_store = this.props.store || [];
        let obj = unit_store[unit_store.length - 1];
        let { search_payload } = this.props;
        let payload = { ...search_payload };
        if (payload.sortBy) {
            if (payload.sortBy === "id") {
                payload.lastKey = obj[payload.sortBy];
            } else {
                payload.lastKey = obj[payload.sortBy + 'Srt'];
            }
```

**The redux part is implemented differently for every component which has increased the code length so much.**